# List messages in hornetmq queue on jboss 7.1.1

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

I want to list jms messages in  hornetmq queue on jboss 7.1.1

I've tried several approaches :

1. Using **QueueBrowser** - always empty list
2. **listJmsqserverControl.listMessages(null)** - getting exception
3. Calling method "**list-messages**" on the MXBean - always empty list

It looks like Hornetmq is a block box.

Can anyone advice my on how to list messages in hornetmq queue? 
Or maybe better to switch to the other JMS broker?

Comment: Take a look to 'Core Queue Management' part of documentation. you can invoke operations on queues, defined in org.hornetq.api.core.management.QueueControl class, by sending a special (management) message to "hornetq.management" queue.

Answer (score 7):

via jboss-cli.sh
{locate jboss-cli.sh, connect}

[domain@1.1.1:9999 /]  /host=node1/server=server1/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/jms-queue=ExpiryQueue:list-messages-as-json

{Hint - use tabs in jboss-cli to get auto complete{

[domain@1.1.1:9999 /] /host=node1/server=server1/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/jms-queue=ExpiryQueue:count-messages
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => 93476L
}

Comment: There is a lot of other useful commands e.g: change-message-priority, read-resource-description, change-messages-priority, move-message, remove-message, count-messages, move-messages, remove-messages, expire-message, pause, reset-message-counter, expire-messages, read-attribute, resume, list-consumers-as-json, read-children-names, send-message-to-dead-letter-address, list-message-counter-as-html, read-children-resources, send-messages-to-dead-letter-address, read-children-types, undefine-attribute, read-operation-description, write-attribute, read-operation-names, list-messages, read-resource

Answer (score 3):

Try with jboss-cli, pausing the queue:

```
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/jms-queue=<Queue-name>/:pause
```

and after list the messages:

```
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/jms-queue=<Queue-name>/:list-messages
```

Then resume, when you are done:

```
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/jms-queue=<Queue-name>/:resume
```

Comment: From my experience, I cannot list the documents that are "in delivery" unless I pause the Queue.